# Is it possible to use UINavigationViewController as one part of ViewController

Tags: iphone

I have a project in which I have constructed myself's multi viewcontrollers.
I also hope to use UINavigationViewController's convenience in one module of function.

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't sufficiently clear for us to give you an answer. Did you mean "I have a project that has multiple custom view controllers, and I want to use a UINavigationViewController to switch between them" or "... and I want to use a UINavigationViewController with one (or some) of them"?